# How to pass values between functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I know it would be easy using methods and attributes, but I can not just do it with functions. It's for a wordpress plugin so I also can not use global variables.

I would like to know how to pass the GET value of the `Post()` function to `Funend ()`. 
My unsuccessful attempt:

```
<?php
//FUNCTION 1
function Name($a)
{


    return $a;  
}

//FUNCTION 2

function Post()
{
    $city = $_GET['city'];

    Name($city);

}

//FUNCTION 3
function Funend()
{

    $funend = Name();

        ///DEBUG
        ob_start(); 
        var_dump($funend);
        $data = ob_get_clean();
        $txt = fopen('bug.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($txt,  $data);
        fclose($txt);
        //DEBUG 
}
Post();
Funend();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - Functions always in small letters.

If you just wants to pass $_GET value to Funend() you can pass it like this

```
<?php
    //FUNCTION 1
    function Name($a){
        Funend($a);//Calling Funend()function
    }
    //FUNCTION 2
    function Post(){
        Name($_GET['city']); //Calling Name()function
    }
    //FUNCTION 3
    function Funend($city){
        ///DEBUG
        ob_start(); 
        var_dump($city);
        $data = ob_get_clean();
        $txt = fopen('bug.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($txt,  $data);
        fclose($txt);
        //DEBUG 
    }
    Post(); //Calling Post()function
?>
```

Comment: This would not work I simplified the question but: $ _GET ['city'] So it is accessible within function Post ()

Answer (score 2):

Functions can accept values (called *arguments* or *parameters*) and they can return values (simply called *return value*).

If the objective is to let `Funend()` receive a value from `Post()`, you could do this:

```
function Post() {
    return $_GET[ 'city' ]; // return value
}

// accepts one (explicit) argument
function Funend( $city ) {
    /* do something with $city */
}

Funend( Post() );
```

That last line is basically a condensed version of:

```
$city = Post(); // temporarily store the return value of Post() in $city;
Funend( $city ); // pass $city as an argument to Funend();
```

except it doesn't use the intermediate variable `$city`, thereby keeping the outer scope clean of variables.

Another way to do it could be:

```
function Post() {
    $city = $_GET[ 'city' ];

    Funend( $city ); // call Funend() from within Post()

    return $city; // perhaps return the city as well?
}

function Funend( $city ) {
    /* do something with $city */
}

Post(); // now we only have to call Post()
```

But then `Post()` is coupled to `Funend()`, which makes it less flexible, because now you can't call `Post()` anymore without automatically invoking `Funend()` as well.

Comment: Is there any way to do this by using the Name function as an intermediary?

Comment: Something like `Funend( Name( Post() ) );`, you mean? Let me know if that's sufficient enough for you. If not, I'll elaborate in my answer tomorrow. Got to get some sleep now.